# I have never created Quantcast account why still they show my site's Quantcast rank?

Tags: seo, ranking, quantcast

I have never registered for Quantcast and placed Quantcast code on my site.
Still, on many website value checker sites I found some number as Quantcast for my site.

Does this rank really matter for a SEO? If yes, then is there any powerful method get a better ranking?

Comment: Is this a brand new domain name or did you recycle a domain name that was used in the past?

Comment: i purchased it brand new.. that domain had never registered before.. and my domain age is 1 year

Comment: If you look up your domain on www.quantcast.com, does it state that statistics are directly measured or estimated?

Comment: One of many WAG (Wilde Aed Guess) site traffic analyzers out there. Often when you sign up, you find the traffic reported drops as the guessed estimate is off by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Quantcast retrieves its data using two methods:

- by direct submission
- while crawling whois registry.

So when a new entry is made to the WHOIS registry, Quantcast wil detect it soon, and add it to its database. This is the same that happens with "about me" websites, and domain value checker websites.

Don't bother with the score of your website that Quantcast provides you. It is in no way an indication of your SEO campaigns.